# Finding values which is both present and not present as per conditions (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am pretty new to SQL. I have a 'Transactions' table with columns 'Model_Id' and 'Tran_date'. I have another 'Model' table with columns 'Model_Id' and 'Model_Name'. I want all the model names from 'Transactions' table which were sold in the year 2017 but not in the year 2018. How can I use the `Where` statement to get the required values in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Although I have supplied an answer here (in the form of pseudo-SQL) when posting a question like this you really need to supply Sample data and expected results as a bare minimum. Otherwise volunteers here have to guess your DDL and data, which is probably mean it'll be wrong (but possibly helpful).

As I said above, however, this is pseudo-SQL, but should help you:

```
SELECT YourColumns
FROM Model M
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM [Transaction] T
              WHERE T.ModelID = M.ModelID
                AND T.TranactionDate >= '20170101'
                AND T.TranactionDate < '20180101')
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [Transaction] T
                  WHERE T.ModelID = M.ModelID
                    AND T.TranactionDate >= '20180101'
                    AND T.TranactionDate < '20190101');
```

Comment: This assumes `TranactionDate`  has some reasonable formart formally ('YYYY-MM-DD') or `00:00:0000` time component.

Comment: @YogeshSharma is assumed that the OP is storing they date data as a date(time). If they aren't, then there is a most fundamental problem with their data design! Date data isn't stored in a format, and `yyyyMMdd` is a deterministic input format, so will always work as intended against the correct data type; which means if they are using a proper data type your point isn't relevant (as the data has no format).

Comment: For example `DECLARE @DT datetime = '19000101'; SELECT @DT; SET @DT = '01/01/1900'; SELECT @DT;` will held 2, identical datasets, as the `datetime` won't store the format that was used.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
SELECT m.Model_Name
FROM Transactions t
JOIN Model m on m.model_id=t.model_id
    and year(t.tran_date)=2017
LEFT JOIN Model mm on mm.model_id=t.model_id
    and year(t.tran_date)=2018
WHERE mm.model_id is null
```

Comment: How does that eliminate models that were sold in 2018? Also, using `YEAR()` in your `WHERE` or `JOIN` clauses will make your your query non-SARGable, which for a big table will be cause significant performance loss

Comment: yea, i just read it, edited answer.
and agreed for big tables.